# Time zone for house taxes due in ArcheAge?

Tags: arche-age

When I look at a house or another building in ArcheAge I can see the building's informations, in particular the time when the land property will expire due to unpaid taxes.

The question is: in what time zone is expressed that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: I was previously mistaken.  The time that is shown as a time that something will come out of protection is the actual time of YOUR machine.  All of the times are based off of the timezone of the client PC and recalculated appropriately.

Comment: I've read this on the official forum too, thx for the confirmation ;-)